# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Computational Science breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0          9
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            60        243
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               13         30
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         11         68
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                1         90
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               103        660
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              182        750
Tags merged                                       7          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             0          3
Tag synonyms created                              5          0
Tag highlight language set                        2          0
Questions reopened                                1          0
Questions migrated                                1          0
Questions flagged⁴                                1        158
Questions closed                                206        131
Question flags handled⁴                         112         47
Posts unlocked                                    0          2
Posts undeleted                                   3         15
Posts locked                                      0         11
Posts deleted⁵                                   96        684
Posts bumped                                      0        722
Comments undeleted                                1          0
Comments flagged                                  2        197
Comments deleted⁶                               122        437
Comment flags handled                            88        111
Answers flagged                                   1        103
Answer flags handled                             86         18
All comments on a post moved to chat              1          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...